# Why do I need to compile and fit a pretrained model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to load in a pretrained model and start testing on images.

This is the code that I thought would work:

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Preprocessing
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
#Preprocessing

test_loss, test_acc = base_model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Instead it says: "You must compile a model before training/testing"

Looking here https://keras.io/applications/ at InceptionV3: they seem to be compiling and fitting the model after importing it. Why do they do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InceptionV3 model was trained on very different images in comparison to Fashion MNIST.  What you are seeing in the tutorial is an instance of **transfer learning**.  Roughly in transfer learning, you can split up the model into a feature extraction module and a classification module.  The goal of the convolutional and pooling layers are to automate the feature extractions so that we can produce an ideal transformation from raw image pixels to a representative set of features that describes the images well.

These images are then fed to a classification module, where the goal is to take these features and actually do classification.  That's the goal of the dense layers that are attached after the convolutional and pooling.  Also note that the InceptionV3 model is trained on ImageNet images, which have 1000 classes.  In order to successfully apply ImageNet to the Fashion MNIST dataset, you will need to retrain the Dense layers so that the conv and pooling layers can take the features extracted from the images and perform classification on that.  Therefore, set `include_top=False` as what you have done, but you'll also have to attach some Dense layers and retrain those.  Also make sure that you specify the last layer to have 10 classes due to the Fashion MNIST dataset.

However, some gotchas are that InceptionV3 takes in 299 x 299 sized images where Fashion MNIST takes in 28 x 28.  You will need to resize the images, as well as artificially pad the images in the third dimension so that they are RGB.  Because going from 28 x 28 to 299 x 299 requires a factor of 10 increase in both dimensions, resizing images up to this resolution probably will not look well perceptually.  InceptionV3 can load in a model where you can change the expected input image size.  The smallest image size unfortunately is 75 x 75 for InceptionV3, so we'll have to use that then resize up to 75 x 75. To resize the image, you can use Scikit-images [`resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) method from `skimage.transform`.  Also, if you plan on using InceptionV3, you'll need to preprocess the input images like they've done in their network prior to training.

Therefore:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input # New
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(75, 75, 3))

# Now add some Dense Layers - let's also add in a Global Average Pooling layer too
# as a better way to "flatten"
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
# and a softmax layer -- 10 classes
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

# Create new model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# Make sure we set the convolutional layers and pooling layers so that they're not trainable
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

#Preprocessing
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
train_images = train_images.astype(np.float) / 255.0 # Change
test_images = test_images.astype(np.float) / 255.0 # Change

# Preprocessing the images
from skimage.transform import resize
train_images_preprocess = np.zeros((train_images.shape[0], 75, 75, 3), dtype=np.float32)

for i, img in enumerate(train_images):
    img_resize = resize(img, (75, 75), anti_aliasing=True)
    img_resize = preprocess_input(img_resize).astype(np.float32)
    train_images_preprocess[i] = np.dstack([img_resize, img_resize, img_resize])

del train_images

test_images_preprocess = np.zeros((test_images.shape[0], 75, 75, 3), dtype=np.float32)

for i, img in enumerate(test_images):
    img_resize = resize(img, (75, 75), anti_aliasing=True)
    img_resize = preprocess_input(img_resize).astype(np.float32)
    test_images_preprocess[i] = np.dstack([img_resize, img_resize, img_resize])

del test_images

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train it
model.fit(train_images_preprocess, train_labels, epochs=15)

# Now evaluate the model - note that we're evaluating on the new model, not the old one
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images_preprocess, test_labels)

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
```

Take note that I had to change the expected input shape of the data from the InceptionV3 base model so that it's 75 x 75 x 3 with 3 being it's expecting colour images.  Also, I had to convert your data to floating-point before dividing by 255 or the data will still be unsigned 8-bit integer so the only values would be either 0 or 1, thus significantly decreasing your accuracy.  Also, I created new arrays that store the RGB versions of the images that are not only resized to 75 x 75, but are also preprocessed using the same method that InceptionV3 uses prior to training their images.  One other thing I should mention is that we need to set the layers prior to the Dense layers so that we don't train on them.  We want to use these layers to provide the feature descriptors for the images that get pumped into the Dense layers to do the classification.  Finally, take note that the labels for the training and test data are enumerated from 0 - 9.  Therefore, the loss function you need will be the sparse categorical cross-entropy one which is designed to take in single-valued labels.  The categorical cross-entropy loss function expects one-hot encoding.

We finally compile the model so we can set it up for training, then train it.  Finally we evaluate the test data accuracy.  This will of course require some tuning, especially the number of Dense layers you want, and the number of epochs to choose for training.

## Warning

The resizing of the images and creating a new array for them will take some time as we're looping over 60000 training images and 10000 test images respectively.  You'll need to be patient here.  In order to conserve memory, I delete the original training and test images from memory to compensate for the preprocessed images.

## Ending Note

Because the Fashion MNIST dataset has considerably less degrees of freedom than ImageNet, you can get away with getting a high accuracy model using fewer layers than normal.  The ImageNet database consists of images that have varying levels of distortion, object orientations, placements and size.  If you constructed a model that consisted of just a few conv and pool layers, combined with a flattening and a couple of dense layers, not only will it take less time to train, but you'll get a decently performing model.

Answer (score 2):

Most pre-trained image classification models are pre-trained on the ImageNet dataset, so you're loading the parameter weights from that training when you call `base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`. The `include_top=False` parameter actually chops off the prediction layer from the model, which you are expected to add on and train on your own dataset, Fashion MNIST in this case.

The transfer learning approach doesn't completely get rid of all training, but makes it so you only need to fine tune the model based on your dataset's specific data. Since the model has already learned how to recognize basic and even somewhat complex shapes by training on ImageNet, now it just needs to be trained to recognize what certain combinations of shapes mean in the context of your data.

That being said, I believe you should still be able to call `model.predict(x)` on some preprocessed image, x, if you change `include_top=False` to `include_top=True`, although the model will try to classify the image into one of ImageNet's 1000 classes and not into one of Fashion MNIST's classes.

Answer (score 1):

The example you are showing in the Keras documentation does not the same as you want to do. They fit a model in order to perform transfer learning.

You seem to want to just load a pretrained model and then evaluate its loss/accuracy on some dataset. The problem is that in order to call `model.evaluate`, you first need to define a loss and metrics (including accuracy), and for that you need to call `model.compile(loss = ..., metrics = ..., optimizer = ...)`, just because it is the only Keras call that sets the loss and metrics of a model.

If for some reason you don't want to do that, you could just call `y_pred = model.predict` with your dataset, and use any python implementation of the loss and metrics you want on `y_true` and `y_pred`. This would not require to compile the model as you externalize the evaluation.